# insert into multiple tables with register form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

i have a register form and I tried to insert information into multiple tables but that second query doesn't work , i know i have to use user_id for second one but can someone explain to me how?

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname,email,password) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password')";

    $sql2="INSERT INTO address(phone,city,address) VALUES('$phone','$city','$address')";


$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "Account Successfully Created";
} else {
echo "Failure!";
}
```

Comment: Can you give the error message ?

Comment: Because you didnt execute your `$sql2` query.

Answer (score 1):

A quick/dodgy solution would be:

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname,email,password) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password')";    
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
    $userid = mysql_insert_id();
    $sql2="INSERT INTO address(userid, phone,city,address) VALUES($userid, '$phone','$city','$address')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

You should use the newer mysql functions though - mysqli
 http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php as mysql is deprecated.
If you decide to stick with mysql though - at the very least mysql_real_escape those values :)